# Is it possible for industrial revolution to happen without colonialism?

Tags: internal-consistency, technology, alternate-history

As we all know, with Christopher Columbus re-"discovering" America in 1492, the wondrous Age of Discovery began - and with it new dreams of conquest and wealth, that became realized in the way of imperialistic colonialism, during which Europe managed to subjugate most of the world due to their advanced military technology and immune system.

I have stumbled upon various threads discussing the effects it would have on the *colonized*, now I am asking about the *colonizers*.

**The conditions are as follows:**

- Europeans started exploring the world in similar ways, but found the, in our history, colonised to be economically and militarily on more or less equal grounds.
- The African and American states are prospering, and should europeans not decide to make enemies, they will make friends, allies and trading partners.
- The "prospering states" do not span the whole continents.
- *Some* colonies are therefore plausible.
- Humans can be very cruel and greedy and that does not apply only to europeans.
- Between some of the states/tribes/whatever on the continents, there will be infighting and strife for domination. Slavery is still a major trade between the victorious parties of each continent.

**Background**

From what I understand colonies were important as:

- the source of cheap labor workers from slavery (far away and removed
  from european moralists and intellectuals);
- new land to build plantations on (cotton, cocoa, tobacco, etc.),
- new metal and mineral deposits (gems, gold, silver, coal, etc.)

These things meant money and trade. Colonialism caused among other things unseen economical growth and rapid development of mercantilism - and capitalism. With its many colonies, Great Britain became a rich, influential superpower.

Should my conditions apply, the most straghtforward consequences could be as follows:

- Europeans (British Empire as well), either need to actually *pay* for the trade goods, since they come from allied countries over the seas.
- Or they would need to start a full blown conquest, either to

  - defeat the prospering countries,
  - defeat weaker countries/conquer territories and then defend them.
- = This would require to raise an additional army, feed it, to fight against uprisings of nations/tribes armed with european technologies and seeking autonomy, and to fend off regional (neighbour) enemies *and* fellow european nations.

Basically, ***It would cost a lot.***

Now, the problem is, that industrial revolution, starting in the 1760s, began in England and was built upon its, [as wikipedia states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Industrial_Revolution#Causes_in_Britain), "legal and cultural foundations". Those, however, largely stem from Britains position as a capitalistic superpower that gained influence and stability as a *colonial power* in the first place.

> **Is it possible for the world to have a place prosperous and visionary-friendly enough with a small amount of important colonies and mostly
>   non-exploitative trade between nations of similar standing, so that
>   conditions for the industrial revolution are met, or was the colonisation so crucial to the industrial development of Europe that it is either really problematic, or not possible at all?**

**In-depth Questions**

- Would it still happen, but would end up being post-poned? For how long? Decades? Centuries?
- Would it still happen in Britain? If not, then where would it be most likely?

**Notes**

- This question is based on a setting with technology roughly corresponding to 1830s, but where (as you can guess), colonisation is not a thing - or at least not the scope we know.
- The purpose of this question is to make sure, industrial setting, in fact, is plausible without colonisation and perhaps to sort of categorize the impacts a lack of colonialism has on the setting in other aspects I might not have considered (e.g. someone argumenting why it would be impropable).
- If this happens to be too broad, assume that the changes are as small as possible (as big as they might be).
- My knowledge of history, and therefore these formulations, are focused more on Africa and America, but answers considering Oceania, Australia and Asia (the colonized parts obviously) are more than welcome.

Thank you for your insights.

Comment: Hi weirdflex, and welcome to Worldbuilding! This is a fascinating topic, but is currently a bit broad for our site, which is built around a one-question best-answer format. If you're able to narrow down your question to be more answerable, it'll be much less likely to be closed as "too-broad". Until then, I've voted to place your question on hold so you can make edits without worrying about unhelpful answers. I'd also recommend checking out our [Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7183/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) for some feedback before re-posting.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE. When you have a moment, please [click here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388) to learn more about our culture. Please also read our meta posts about [high concept questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868) and [open-ended questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6654). Questions like these are not a good fit for our site because [SE is not a discussion forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums/92110#92110).

Comment: Oh, I understand, thank you!

Comment: Your edit to this question, whilst making it a different question doesn't make it (in my view) much less broad. Vote to leave closed (from review).

Comment: I know it probably still sounds complicated, but the core of this question really is just a reality check on whether the change is too big to be overcome and be plausible. Alternatively, looking at it from another perspective, I could reword it as: Would trade with the prospering nations be profitable enough to overcome the economical deficit so that industrial revolution could happen? - That is basically what I mean. Is that still not specific enough?

Comment: Japan and Germany (among others) managed to industrialize without colonies.

Comment: Our [help/on-topic] explains that questions must be specific and answerable, must include context, must include restrictions/requirements, and should include research.  Kudos for a well-presented question, but it's anything but specific.  An entire PhD thesis would be required to rationally answer this question.  I wish you'd followed up with one of your previous comments.  This question would be much, much better presented as a [tag:reality-check].  (\*continued\*)

Comment: HOWEVER, an RC question means that you DON'T ask a question.  You are required to present a complete scenario and tag it [tag:reality-check], it's then up to us to provide a critique of the scenario.  *You cannot ask how to fill in gaps in your scenario during a Reality Check question.*

Comment: At the beginning of the 18th century England was not a superpower of any kind, "capitalistic" or otherwise. It was much smaller and poorer than France, for example, and *very* much smaller and poorer than the Spanish Empire. At the beginning of the 18th century no European power could even dream of taking on India and China, which were the world's economic powerhouses, or the Ottoman Empire, or the Persian Empire. You have it exactly backwards; Europe rose to dominate the world *because* of the industrial revolution.

Comment: AlexP really hit the mark one of the main reasons Columbus and other Europeans tried to find alternate routes to Asia is because of the Ottomans who where arguably the major power for hundreds of years. Even then in Africa the Europeans ran into developed states they where unable to conqueror ex: The Kingdom of the Kongo. The major conquests of Africa come after the industrial revolution.